# jQuery - hide text after element

Tags: jquery, hide

I have such source code:

```
<div class="abc">
<strong>ddffgg</strong>
qwerty
</div>
```

I want to hide text which is after `</strong>` - in this example it's: `qwerty` - how to do it with jQuery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var size = $('.abc').css('font-size');
$('.abc').css('font-size', 0);
$('.abc').children().css('font-size', size);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2pj8x/

or

```
$($('.abc strong')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span style="display:none"></style>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2pj8x/1

Comment: The latter worked best for me (although I had to change `nextSibling` to `previousSibling`). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i need for something. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

[**.hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) won't hide the text nodes, it hides only elements.You should wrap the content you want to hide under a `span` or `div` etc. and then you will be able to hide them using `.hide()`

[See a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/3uq2X/)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the text into another div and then hide that.

```
<div class="abc">
<strong>ddffgg</strong>
<div id="toggleText">qwerty</div>
</div>
```

Then just toggle the second div with jquery:

```
$('#toggleText').hide(); //to hide
$('#toggleText').show(); //to show
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text inside a `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>` etc, then:
say you use:

`<p class="delete">qwerty</p>`

`$("p").removeClass("delete");`  then the class, and text, is gone